# If $\Vert e^{tA}\Vert\to 0$ as $t\to \infty$, then $\sigma(A)\subset \{\lambda\in \Bbb{C}:\,\Bbb{Re}(\lambda)<0\}$

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-equations, matrix-calculus

Assume that $\Vert e^{tA}\Vert\to 0$ as $t\to \infty$. I want to prove that 
 \begin{align}\sigma(A)\subset \{\lambda\in \Bbb{C}:\,\Bbb{Re}(\lambda)<0\}\end{align}
where $\sigma(A)$ is set of all eigenvalues of matrix $A\in M_{n\times n}(\Bbb{R})$

**MY TRIAL**

Let $\lambda\in \sigma(A).$ Then, then wwe can find $x\neq 0$ s.t. 
\begin{align}Ax=\lambda x  \end{align}

Since $\Vert e^{tA}\Vert\to 0$ as $t\to \infty,$ then $\forall\,\epsilon>0,\,\exists\, n_0\in\Bbb{N}$ s.t. $\forall\,n\geq n_0$
\begin{align}\Vert e^{tA}\Vert<  \epsilon\end{align}
but I don't know how to put these statements together in bringing up the right proof. Can someone show me how? It seems that the answer provided in the following post gave a related solution [A real matrix whose eigenvalues have all negative real parts](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/972517/a-real-matrix-whose-eigenvalues-have-all-negative-real-parts?rq=1) but I don't know how to employ it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $\| x\| =1$ and $Ax = \lambda x$. Then \begin{align*}
\\exp(tA)x = \left( \sum_{i=0}^\infty t^nA^n/n! \right)x = \sum_{i=0}^\infty t^nA^n x/n! = \left( \sum_{i=0}^\infty t^n\lambda^n/n! \right)x = \exp(t \lambda) x.
\end{align*}
Thus $\exp(t \lambda)$ is an eigenvalue of $\exp(tA)$ and $\| \exp(t A)\| \ge |\exp(t \lambda)|$.

Now, what happens with $\exp(t \lambda)$ if $\Re(\lambda) \ge 0$ and we let $t \to \infty$? Can you get a contradiction with $\lim_{t \to \infty} \| \exp(tA) \| = 0$?

Also, this only works if $\lambda$ is real, what happens if $\lambda$ is exactly complex? Can you show that $\exp(t \lambda)$ is again an eigenvalue of $\exp(tA)$?

Comment: Thanks a million times! I'l go through the proof and get back at you if I have questions!

Comment: Please, how did you get $\| \exp(t A)\| \ge \exp(t \lambda)?$

Comment: For matrices $B$, we have $\|B\| = \sup_{\|y\| =1} \| By\|$. Thus if $Bx = \lambda x$ and $\|x\|=1$, we have $\|B\| =  \sup_{\|y\| =1} \| By\| \ge \|Bx\| = |\lambda|\|x\| = |\lambda|$. Added the missing absolute values in the post.

Comment: Thanks a lot! The proof goes the same way, right?

Comment: I don't quite get you here! "Can you show that $\exp(t \lambda)$ is again an eigenvalue of $\exp(tA)$?" Do I have to show it again? If I have to, I think it follows the same approach right?

Comment: @Micheal Not exactly, because if $\lambda$ is actually complex, we can no longer find eigenvectors for it in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Consider for example the matrix $\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ -1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$.